# mix single channel images into color image

Tags: bash, imagemagick

each representing a channel and I want to merge them into a single one, like RGB image. The images are RAW, so no file header. I have managed to mix them with

```
cat imgPl0.raw imgPl1.raw imgPl2.raw >> img.rgb
```

but this is mixing the planes one after the other, but is there a way to do an interlaced mix ?

---

Maybe using imagemagick there is another way ?

---

Well, what I need at the output is a rgb image (not a png, sadly imagemagick is creating a png as output) containing the data interlaced. To be more explicit, `cat`-ing the images is going to make a rgb image plane-interlaced (that is rrrrrr...ggggggg...bbbbbbb). What I want is an *operation* that is creating a rgb image line-interlaced (that is rrr...ggg...bbb...rrr...ggg...bbb...rrr...ggg...bbb...). Sorry for not being explicit from the beginning.

About the data, it seems it is 12 bpp or 14 bpp little endian

Comment: `bash` doesn't know anything about image files, nor does `cat`; you need a program that does.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that there is a way to do it in bash, but it may be also imagemagick. I edited the question

Comment: While correcting your question, you should also indicate if the data are 8 or 16 bit per sample.

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick offers a few techniques, but you'll need to be responsible for defining all the information missing from the headers. Stuff like image size, quantum depth, and colorspace.

One approach.

```
 convert -size 70x46 -depth 8 \
         r:imgPl0.raw g:imgPl1.raw b:imgPl2.raw \
         -set colorspace RGB -combine -colorspace sRGB \
         output.rgb
```

Another option is to create a blank canvas, and copy the data from the raw files over to the correct canvas channels.

```
convert -size 70x46 xc: -depth 8 \
        r:imgPl0.raw -compose CopyRed -composite \
        g:imgPl1.raw -compose CopyGreen -composite \
        b:imgPl2.raw -compose CopyBlue -composite \
        -colorspace sRGB output.rgb
```

Other examples can be found [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#combine).

*Also note:* I'm assuming that these `.raw` data files only contain single channel samples, are unsigned character color sizes, and have a 70x46 image size. *YMMV*

**Update**

> Well, what I need at the output is a rgb image (not a png, sadly imagemagick is creating a png as output)

Sorry about that. Just switch `output.png` to `output.rgb`. ImageMagick will do the rest.

> About the data, it seems it is 12 bpp or 14 bpp little endian

Adjust `-depth` from 8 to 12, or 14 bits-per-part.
There's also a [`-endian LSB`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#endian) option, but I don't think that's needed.

> What I want is an *operation* that is creating a rgb image line-interlaced

Easy. Set the [`-interlace Line`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#interlace) options.

---

So... My previous answer is still helpful, but just needs some additional options.

```
 convert -size 70x46 -depth 12 \
         r:imgPl0.raw g:imgPl1.raw b:imgPl2.raw \
         -set colorspace RGB -combine -colorspace sRGB \
         -interlace Line output.rgb
```

or

```
convert -size 70x46 xc: -depth 12 \
        r:imgPl0.raw -compose CopyRed -composite \
        g:imgPl1.raw -compose CopyGreen -composite \
        b:imgPl2.raw -compose CopyBlue -composite \
        -colorspace sRGB -interlace Line output.rgb
```

Hope that get's you close.

Comment: you wrote a good answer, but I figured out that this is not really what I need, so I updated the question,

Answer (score 0):

If your data is 8 bits per sample, you can do it like this which whilst not very efficient, doesn't require any code writing or compiling or anything:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Bytes per row
bpr=100
row=0


# Loop through all rows of file
while :; do
   # Read a row from each channel and output on stdout redirected to result.rgb
   for ((chan=0;chan<3;chan++)); do
      dd if=imgPl${chan}.raw bs=$bpr count=1 skip=$row > row.tmp 2> /dev/null
      [ ! -s row.tmp ] && exit
      cat row.tmp
   done
   ((row+=1))
done > result.rgb
```